# JavaScript function syntax error confusion

Tags: javascript, function

I don't know whats wrong with this code

```
  var createWorker = function(){
  var task1 = function(){
     console.log("this is job1");
  };
  var task2 = function(){
     console.log("this is job2");
  };

   return
   {
      job1: task1,
      job2: task2
   };
};
var worker = createWorker();
worker.job1();
worker.job2();
```

This gives the syntax error but I think the syntax is right. Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error message? What line does it refer to?

Answer (score 8):

You are returning `undefined`, because of the [automatic semicolon insertation (ASI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

```
return                            // colon is inserted here
     {                            // never reached
         job1: task1,
         job2: task2
     };
```

You could move the bracket into the line of the return statement.

```
return {
         job1: task1,
         job2: task2
     };
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz. Finally It works. I did not know about such minor details. (Y)